# Is there something like bootstrap panels and jumbotron in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I'm pretty new with android layout.

I am creating an android app which needs some promising layout and UI.

Need something like bootstraps' `panel panel-default` and `jumbotron`.

My requirements are clearly visible in this pic.

[image]

We can see them in Google playstore app as well as in whatsapp. I have quite searched about it and tried using `GridLayout` with background (but doesn't have shadows and looks like flat image), I hope I'll get answer here.

What are they called and how to use them.Please mention the code or give references.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Nope, they're not available by default. You're going to have to make them on your own. If you're interested in the new material design implemented by Google, then this link might be helpful to you. https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

Comment: You might also be interested in [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)

Answer (score 0):

I've used a custom xml drawable as my layout background to provide a similar effect.

Create a file in your drawable folder called something like card_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/background_material_light" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="3dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/card_shadow" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:top="3dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/card_white" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Then you need to define the two colors card_shadow & card_white in your values/color.xml file:

```
<color name="card_white">#ffffffff</color>
<color name="card_shadow">#CABBBBBB</color>
```

After that you can pass in your drawable as the background of a layout such as:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/card_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/card_background">
```

And that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve, what you try to implement using `CardView`.

The `CardView` widget is part of the `v7 Support Libraries`. To use it in your project, add the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

In order to use the `CardView` you need to add it to your layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

For more customized CardView you can refer: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib